# Open source UWP app, can I make the app identity public

Tags: uwp

I have an open-source UWP app for which I want to use AppVeyor to automatically create the appxupload package for me.

I stumpled upon [this instructions](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/15/building-an-app-for-a-3rd-party-how-to-package-their-store-app/#UVI7GteIhAAAjljq.97) on how to configure the project to create the appxupload package without requiring the App_StoreKey.pfx certificate file.

Now I'm wondering if I can make these values, the app identity, public, or if someone can do any harm with them?

I mean these values right here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm wondering if I can make these values, the app identity, public, or if someone can do any harm with them?

**Yes**, they can. By all means distribute your project's source code - but anything that uniquely identifies you as a developer (and the publishing chain) must be kept secret because that's how consumers of the application can trust that a certain build they get really is from you, the original developer, and not a malicious third-party who modified the program to do something evil (e.g. upload users' contacts list to a spamming service) - if you were to make your signing files publicly available then anyone can imitate you.

Comment: That's exactly the part I'm wondering about, do I really publish the signing files that way? In the instruction is this part: (Note: When the app has been uploaded to the Dev Center, the Store will automatically strip out this signing signature and will replace it with the Store signature anyways.)